# Can I make a HTML input form field optional?

Tags: python, html, flask

Hi so I have a form in a HTML file. The input data is processed using Python and Flask using request.form. However, I would like some of the input fields to be optional. Currently I get the following error:

```
 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

I believe that this is due to some fields being empty.

My form is designed in such a way that some fields only appear when a radio button is checked. The issues arises when the form is submitted and the radio button is not checked, as the form just treats them as empty.

Here is my form code:

```
    <form action = "makeBooking" method = "POST" >
        Booking ID <input type = "number" name = "bookingid" ><br>
        Customer ID <input type = "number" name = "customerid" ><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice">
        <label for="choice">Tick if new customer</label>
        <div class="reveal-if-active">
            First Name <input type = "test" name = "firstname" VALUE="x" ><br>
            Surname <input type = "text" name = "surname"  VALUE="x"><br>
            Billing Address <input type = "text" name = "address" VALUE="x" ><br>
            Email <input type = "text" name = "email"  VALUE="x"><br>
        </div>
        Flight ID <input type = "number" name = "flightid" ><br>
        Number of Seats <input type = "number" name = "numofseats" ><br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" >
    </form>
```

The following Python code is where the error lies as they are submitted as empty if the radio button is unchecked.

```
bookingid = request.form['bookingid']
customerid = request.form['customerid']
flightid = request.form['flightid']
numseats = request.form['numofseats']

if request.form['choice']:
    firstname = request.form['firstname']
    surname = request.form['surname']
    address = request.form['address']
    email = request.form['email']

    #do some SQL insert statements with ALL the form data

else: 
    #do some sql insert statements with the none hidden statements
```

Anyone have any ideas.

Thanks.

UPDATED: To show my code more clearly.

Comment: You should only execute the mentioned Python code upon the selection of the radio button, so the given answer will probably do the trick. Unrelated; Shouldn't you use a checkbox rather than a stand-alone radio button? You can't easily uncheck those, so a user misclick forces them to fill in the revealed part of the form.

Answer (score 1):

```
if request.form['choice']:
   firstname = request.form['firstname']
   surname = request.form['surname']
   address = request.form['address']
   email = request.form['email']
```

because you want not to process this if radio choice is not selected

Comment: happy now @LennartKloppenburg

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure I quite understand though. I currently have what you suggested (will update my post to reflect that) and it causes an error because I cannot process the form data if the radio button is unchecked. I would like to it to be `if checked process all fields else process non hidden forms' but I can't do that because the error is thrown if any fields is empty.